# Jenkins start build from different users

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

I need to launch several builds on Jenkins. 
But also I need to do it by different users  for example (test1 and test2)  .
Is there any plugin for it or some config file.

I need it because `test1` have special permission for some directories.
and `test2` have special permission for some  other directories.

Or can I change jenkins config somehow as if it was launched from `test1` users with all `test1` user permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any plugin to change the user that Jenkins runs under. However, dependent on the os you have different options. Under Windows, you can use `runas` command and under Linux, there is `su` and `sudo`. `ssh` might be an option too, even if you connect to the box that you are on right now. You have to see in how far you need to use free style projects instead of specialized projects.

However, do you really need to have the permission set the way they are or can you permission test1 to have the special permissions that test2 has. This obviously does not work if testing the permissions is the main purpose of the test.

Alternatively, you can use the node functionality that Jenkins provides. On one and the same server you can not only run the main Jenkins, but also nodes (or slaves). These slaves can run under different users. This will give you the overhead that nodes come with, however, it adds a very simple and clean way to switch users. However, nobody prevents you from having more than one slave running on the same server or having you slave run on different servers.